# Svg.Core - Convert to PNG does not render emojis

Tags: c#, svg, png, emoji

I am trying to render SVG file to PNG with Svg.Core library (Windows 10, NET Core 3.1)

Svg file has text attribute that contains emoji symbols. The following code renders emoji to invalid symbol in output PNG file. Does the library support it? 
May be some software (like special Font) should be installed to support this?

```
private static void ConvertSVGToPNG(string svg, string outpuPath)
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(svg);
            var svgDocument = SvgDocument.Open(doc);            
            var bitmap = svgDocument.Draw();
            bitmap.Save(outpuPath, ImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

Example of SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
 <g font-size="60" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="1" >
   <text x="100" y="75">Some Text    </text>   
 </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: A emojii is a SMS (short text message).  Not an image.  A SVG is xml format.  I think you want to take a snapshot of the image and convert to png, not the SMS.